# "The Museums" or "Museums"?

Tags: articles

One girl tells me about her trip to one city.

She says:

> Collections in art museums are really great.

Shouldn't it be:

> **The** collections in **the** art museums?

I mean, I already know where she is, so she's not talking about all museums and all exhibitions of the world.

Am I right?

Comment: No, it is a general statement. No the, she is not being specific. We address this issue over and over here. Plurals in English without the are for generic statements.

Comment: How did she tell you? In a text message? (Lots of folks skip implied words when texting.) For example: _Having a great time. Collections in art museums are really great._ Wouldn't faze me at all in text from friend.

Comment: @Lambie But she says about the collections she has visited in a particular city

Answer (score 2):

> I mean, I already know where she is, so she's not talking about all museums and all exhibitions of the world. Am I right?

No, you are wrong. She *is* make a generalization, one that encompasses all museums.

It's like saying "**Football games** are a lot of fun to watch".

The reference is not to particular football games but football games *in general*.

Comment: But the question starts "One girl tells me about her trip to one city." In other words, particular museums, not all museums.

Comment: @WeatherVane Exactly. She says about the collections she visited in a particular city.

Comment: @WeatherVane Even if the girl is having a conversation about her trip to one particular city, I don't think the generalisation is incorrect or odd. For example, you might go to see a single football game and, when telling friends about the experience, generalise in the way that Tᴚoɯɐuo has described. In my opinion, she is essentially saying: _"I enjoyed visiting the museum because collections in art museums are really great."_ i.e. expressing her general interest in a particular subject.

Comment: @Weather Vane: It's simply not a relevant fact. I could be telling you about a MU versus West Ham game I went to, and in the next breath I could say *Football games are fun to watch.*    I'm making a generalization even though I had been speaking a moment earlier of a particular game I'd attended.

Comment: Read in a vacuum, I'd agree with this answer. But it's possible to presume some context that would make the statement more specific to this one particular trip.

Comment: @J.R. Not when the speaker uses the plural. Even if they've seen only one football game in their entire life and have almost no basis for making a generalization about football games,  the reference is to football games in general when the phrase is ***Football games** are fun to watch*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Oh. I was talking about the OP's sentence about museums, not your sentence about football games. Still, the definite article could change everything. `Tᴚoɯɐuo, to J.R.:` _How are you enjoying England?_ `J.R., to Tᴚoɯɐuo:` _Having a great time. The football games are fun to watch._ But we agree on your sentence – it's absolutely a generalization.

Comment: I get it about making the generalisation. But what if she means the particular collections in the museums of one particular city and she doesn't care about other collections or museums?

Comment: @Oksana Ya: You could still generalize with respect to that city.  *Collections in New York tend to be more complete than those in smaller cities.*  Or you could speak in particular terms: *I am excited to visit the collections in New York.*

Comment: The girl isn't a native speaker, so she could make a mistake. I understand that if you are talking about some general interest you should drop the articles. @Tᴚoɯɐuo "I am excited to visit the collections in New York". Here you've used 'the'. So shouldn't my example look like this: 'The collections in the art museums'? (if we are talking about THE collections that she saw in THE particular city)

Comment: @OksanaYa We don't care about the girl. The point is for you to understand the usages. Of course, you can **say** and ***she should have said***: "I loved the collections in the museums." [context: when she visited London.]. That's why I invented my apple story for you. But you seem to be resisting the concept.

Comment: @Lambie ok, you've confused me again. So is it [Of course, you can say and she should have said: "I loved the collections in the museums."] or [Yours does need a "the" in that particular context]?

Comment: @Oksana Ya.  You have choices which are driven by context and what it is you want to say.  You can say *I am excited to visit the collections in the art museums of New York*.  But you can also say *I am excited to visit the collections in art museums in New York.* and you can also  say *I am excited to visit collections in art museums in New York.*  They are all valid, and have nuanced differences.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That's what I'm trying to understand. Could you explain me those nuanced differences?

Comment: It could take a few hundred pages :)  You might try searching this site for questions about articles. There are dozens and dozens of them.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I have :) But here's the problem. I know basic rules and I understand all the explanations here, but when it gets to some 'nuanced differences' it's still not obvious what to do. That's why I've asked my question. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Oksana Ya: When there is a prepositional phrase that modifies, restricts, or specifies something about the preceding noun,  the statement changes in ways that may affect whether the article is used or omitted.

Comment: @OksanaYa - I still think we could help you understand it better if you furnished more details about the conversation between you and your friend. I know I'm still curious about whether or not your friend's sentence was typed into social media or spoken in a face-to-face conversation. Plus the way your posed your original question made it difficult to answer. You asked: _Shouldn't "X" be "Y"?_ as though X were wrong and Y was correct. In fact, both X and Y can be correct, depending on the context and what you are trying to say. And the rules with articles tend to be very elastic.

Comment: @J.R. I wrote, 'I mean, I already know where she is, so she's not talking about all museums and all exhibitions of the world'. So I really meant that I thought X was wrong and Y was correct(ish), because she wasn't expressing some general idea but her impression of the trip. Perhaps I didn't make myself very clear in the original question. And she said that in a voice message. It was something like 'I am in this city. I've done that and that. Collections in art museums are really great.' So I think that there should be at least one 'the' :) Maybe even two.

Answer (score 1):

All of them seem clumsy. We know that museums contain collections, so you can refer to the museums themselves.

> The art museums are really great.

This is understood to mean their collections, not their coffee or admission prices. It uses the definite article, because they are particular museums, not museums in general.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so in general conversations about things, the plural is used to mean a general idea:

- Collections in museums are great but I really prefer to see private collections in people's homes.

It does not matter if you know her or not. It depends on whether she is making a general statement or not.

**A Very Short Story**

Oksana **loves apples** but she **doesn't love pears**. [general statement] Yesterday, we went to the produce market and I bought **an apple**. And Oksana bought **a banana**. I asked her: "Why did you buy **a banana**?" She said: "**I bought a banana because the apples [those specific ones at the market] didn't look so great**. I really **love apples** [general statement] but they have to look good. **The apples at the fancy, new store** [those specific ones] are much better. Let's go there next time, we want to buy apples OK?". Ok, I said. "By the way, we were discussing museum collections, weren't we? Before we started talking about apples? I love museum collections, you know, but really prefer private collections in rich people's homes."

**The End**

Notice how an apple becomes the apples. The apples are the ones for sale at the market that day. Not the ones in your grandma's garden. The apples there are probably much better than the ones at the market. This just goes to show you how complicated buying apples can be. :) And I hope the short story will help you "get a handle" on this usage.

Comment: But she says about the collections she visited in a particular city. She doesn't express her opinion about museum collections as such.

Comment: @OksanaYa - I think Lambie is trying to explain how this works in general in English, that is, to explain more than your one particular question about museums. Such explanations are likely to be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @OksanaYa  Well, your comment uses my points.  So, you got it. Allow me to say that  most of the language-learning process involves accepting difference. You have to accept the difference and try to practice patterns that may not exist in your own language. That difference can seem crazy but if you try it, you will at some point internalize it without even realizing it...:) [talks about rather than says about]

Answer (score 0):

In a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/186623/the-museums-or-museums/186628#comment369095_186628), you clarified:

> Perhaps I didn't make myself very clear in the original question. She said it in a voice message. It was something like: *'I am in this city. I've done that and that. Collections in art museums are really great.'* So I think that there should be at least one 'the'. Maybe even two.

Whether or not there "should be" is up for debate. In normal, everyday English, I would expect the definite article(s) to be there. However, if a person elected to leave you a voicemail in [Telegram Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_style) or ["Headlinese"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), then the way it was worded would be legitimate.

In other words, if native speaker left me a voicemail, saying:

> I'm in Venice. Rode a gondola and toured the city on foot. Food is outstanding. Collections in art museums are really great.

then I would think nothing of it. I might wonder if the person leaving me the message was in a hurry, or perhaps deliberately using telegram style for humorous effect because they were giving me news from so far away.

However, if a non-native speaker who frequently struggled with the proper use of articles left me that same message, I might be less inclined to think it was done deliberately for humorous effect and more likely to think that my friend is still working on their mastery of English – but I'd still be happy for the update and glad to know they are having such a good time.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Now I get it. But I'll ask just one more question and I promise I'll stop torturing you :)
Is there a difference between 'THE collections in art museums are really great' and 'THE collections in THE art museums are really great'? Is it a big difference based on some context or is the second 'the' optional in some way?

Comment: @OksamaYa - This is not torture at all. If it was, I would have deleted my account long ago. As to your question, **in the general case**, _"The collections in art museums are really great,"_ refers generically to collections in art museums all over the world, while, _"The collections in **the** art museums are really great,"_ refers to a subset of those museums, presumably identified through context, circumstances, or prior conversation. (In your case, it would mean we were referring to the museums that your friend has visited.)

Comment: Ok, then one more question :) If 'The collections in art museums are really great' is a statement about collections in art museums all over the world, what is the difference between this statement and 'Collections in art museums are really great'? Do 'collections' and 'the collections' mean the same here?

Comment: @OksanaYa - That's the point Lambie was trying to explain: _in general conversations about things, the plural can be used to mean a general idea_, In this particular sentence, you can include or omit the leading article, and both sentences are correct and mean the same thing. The phrase "in art museums" makes it so the plural can work with no determiner. Same with _"Hockey games in Canada are fun to watch"_ and _"The hockey games in Canada are fun to watch."_ However, if I take out the "in Canada" part, then there should be **no** "the" at the front: _"Hockey games are fun to watch."_

Comment: Ooooh ok. I knew that we can use plural with no determiner to generalize, but I couldn't get which one of these possible 'the' in my sentence changes a general idea to a particular one and what happens if you use either just the first one or just the second one. Now I get the difference (hopefully). Thank you!